# Debugging c++ .cpp file using Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I have a solitary .cpp file, and I would very much like to debug it.

Without creating an Xcode project, is there anyway I can debug this using the Xcode debugger?

When I open the file in Xcode to edit and set breakpoints, the program doesn't stop at the break points.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to your specific situation, but there's a bug with most Mac OS X kernels (i.e. xnu-dev's Voodoo kernel) running on AMD processors that prevents debuggers from being able to pause on breakpoints. I had to deal with this a few years ago and until I found out about the kernel bug, it was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't debug via Xcode without a project because without a project, Xcode works only as a file editor with color highlight and so one.

For debugging you need an executable compiled with debug option, which is produced via a compiler. The easy way (but in my opinion the worse) is to make a Xcode project and put the .cpp file there. There is the hard way too (and probably the best for future reference) that is to learn to do it on the terminal, using for instance the g++ (compiler) and gdb (debugger).

Answer (score 1):

If noone answers you later, maybe this post will help you

I'm not a XCode developer, but I know, that to debug a process you need:

- a debugger
- the corresponding (!) code
- the info, which stores a special debugging info, which gives the debugger an opportunity to map from binary process to your C++ (or other) code
- and the process, sure :)

this link could help to understand if you have debugging info

http://www.meandmark.com/xcode3debugging.pdf

you can search words "Debug Information" and try to understand, if you have it or not

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without floundering through xcode, but unfortunately it is possibly more arcane.

Using cmake (https://cmake.org/) you can write a simple CMakeLists.txt to pull in your cpp file:-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(project)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
add_executable(project code.cpp)
```

To generate an xcode project type this:-

```sh
cmake -G Xcode
```

this will create project.xcodeproj

You can now type:-

```sh
open project.xcodeproj
```

and xcode will be launched.